# Sort arraylist in specific order

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I have an arraylist like below:

```
ArrayList<PhoneNumber> arrayListToSort
```

PhoneNumber have following properties

`private String number;`

`private String numberType;`

Number type is like **MOBILE , HOME , OFFICE**

I want to sort `arrayListToSort` by `numberType` of each.

I can do this with simple alphebetical order.

But my problem is how to sort the list by follwing order.

1. MOBILE
2. HOME
3. OFFICE

Comment: `number` should be an enum. It would be easier for the sorting.

Comment: @TomJonckheere this is another question.

Comment: @SashaSalauyou indeed... Thx for noticing! I updated it.

Comment: Why is this another question? Why is it not possible to create a `Comparator` for it?

Comment: @TomJonckheere still another... OP doesn't have a property which can be sorted by natural order, they needs to define this order in some way.

Comment: @AlexisC. NumberType can use as an enum

Comment: @ChinthakaDinadasa in your code, `numberType` is definitely `String`

Comment: @SashaSalauyou well, you could define it in the comperator?

Comment: @ChinthakaDinadasa `private String numberType` does not looks like an enum to me .....

Answer (score 1):

Hey you can try **PhonNumberType with enum** check below code

```
 package test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

enum PhonNumberType {
    MOBILE, HOME, OFFICE
}

class PhoneNumber implements Comparable<PhoneNumber> {
    private String number;
    private PhonNumberType phonNumberType;

    @Override
    public int compareTo(PhoneNumber o) {
        return this.phonNumberType.compareTo(o.phonNumberType);
    }

    public String getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(String number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    public PhonNumberType getNumberType() {
        return phonNumberType;
    }

    public void setNumberType(PhonNumberType phonNumberType) {
        this.phonNumberType = phonNumberType;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "PhoneNumber [number=" + number + ", phonNumberType=" + phonNumberType + "]";
    }

}

public class T {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<PhoneNumber> test = new ArrayList<PhoneNumber>();
        PhoneNumber pn = new PhoneNumber();
        pn.setNumber("1");
        pn.setNumberType(PhonNumberType.HOME);

        test.add(pn);

        pn = new PhoneNumber();
        pn.setNumber("2");
        pn.setNumberType(PhonNumberType.MOBILE);
        test.add(pn);

        pn = new PhoneNumber();
        pn.setNumber("3");
        pn.setNumberType(PhonNumberType.OFFICE);
        test.add(pn);

        Collections.sort(test);

        System.out.println(test);
    }

}
```

> output is : [PhoneNumber [number=2, phonNumberType=MOBILE],
>   PhoneNumber [number=1, phonNumberType=HOME], PhoneNumber [number=3,
>   phonNumberType=OFFICE]]

Answer (score 0):

Your Ranking is no natural order.

To get your goal result, you must define your own Comparator.

By the way, as @Alexis C. says, use an Enum for your numberType

Comment: Answer body is missing.

Answer (score 0):

Use an enum for that:

```
public enum NumberType {
    MOBILE,HOME,OFFICE;
}
```

If your PhoneNumber is comparable:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(PhoneNumber o) {
    return numberType.compareTo(o.numberType);
}
```

It will follow the order described in the enum:

```
MOBILE,HOME,OFFICE
```

Comment: Better to use a custom Comparator in the Collections.sort

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this.

### Use a [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html)

In this approach, you sort the `ArrayList` using a custom `Comparator`.

Here is the `Comparator` code. Notice how it first tries to sort on `numberType`, and then `number`:

```
public class PhoneNumberComparator implements Comparator<PhoneNumber> {
    @Override
    public int compareTo (PhoneNumber lhs, PhoneNumber rhs) {
        int result = lhs.numberType.compareTo(rhs.numberType);
        if (result == 0) {
            result = lhs.number.compareTo(rhs.number);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Then you can call:

```
Comparator c = new PhoneNumberComparator();
arrayListToSort.sort (c)
```

Now by itself, this won't work completely because the sort of `numberType` will just be in string order.  The most convenient way to impose the ordering is to make `numberType` an [enumeration](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html).  Here is the code for that:

```
public enum NumberType { MOBILE, HOME, OFFICE }
```

Then the `PhoneNumber` must be defined so that `numberType` is a `NumberType`:

```
public class PhoneNumber {
    public String number ;
    public NumberType numberType;

    // .......

}
```

(By the way I would encourage you to also make `number` and `numberType` into `private` variables, and add getter methods, as per the [JavaBeans standard](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/jnut/ch06_02.htm).)

### Make `PhoneNumber` Implement [`Comparable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html)

If you are planning to do this sort often, then instead of writing the `Comparator`, you should make `PhoneNumber` implement the `Comparable` interface:

```
public class PhoneNumber implements Comparable <PhoneNumber> {
    public String number ;
    public NumberType numberType;

    // .......

    @Override
    public int compareTo (PhoneNumber rhs) {
        int result = this.numberType.compareTo(rhs.numberType);
        if (result == 0) {
            result = this.number.compareTo(rhs.number);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Then you can just call:

```
arrayList.sort()
```

You still need to make `NumberType` an `enum`, as discussed in the first approach. The above `compareTo()` implementation relies on `NumberType` being `Comparable`; all `enum` instances are automatically `Comparable`.

Notice the similarities and the differences between the `Comparator` and the `compareTo()` implementations. A good discussion of `Comparator` and `Comparable` [can be found here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you make your `NumberType` `enum`, not `String`, its `compareTo()` method will return result based on *order in which enum instances are declared*, not alphabetical:

```
public enum NumberType {
   MOBILE, HOME, OFFICE;
}
```

`MOBILE` now is less than `HOME` and `HOME` is less than `OFFICE`. Now you may sort your collection using custom comparator:

```
list.sort(comparing(PhoneNumber::getNumberType).thenComparing(PhoneNumber::getNumber));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;


public class Main {
    public static void arrayListToSort(ArrayList<PhoneNumber> arrayListToSort) {
        Map<String, Integer> phoneTypeToOrder = new HashMap<>();
        phoneTypeToOrder.put("MOBILE", 0); 
        phoneTypeToOrder.put("HOME", 1);
        phoneTypeToOrder.put("OFFICE", 2);

        Collections.sort(arrayListToSort, new Comparator<PhoneNumber>() {

            @Override
            public int compare(PhoneNumber o1, PhoneNumber o2) {
                if (o1 == null || o1.numberType == null) {
                    return -1;
                }
                if (o2 == null || o2.numberType == null) {
                    return 1;
                }
                Integer o1Order = phoneTypeToOrder.get(o1.numberType);
                Integer o2Order = phoneTypeToOrder.get(o2.numberType);
                return o1Order.compareTo(o2Order);
            }

        });
    }
}

class PhoneNumber {
    String number;

    String numberType;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using a customing "sorting-method" called Comparator. In this Comparator you define a "value" for each your records which will be calculated at runtime. The calculation of this value is entirely up to you. You can for example define that "foo" == 1, "bar" == 2 and "john" == 654. The sorting method of Java will then ask each record for it's "value" and sort accordingly (I think using Quicksort-Algorithm, but I am not sure about this).

Here's a nice little tutorial to get you into this topic and shows how to implement Comparator and Comparable-Interfaces correctly:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_using_comparator.htm

This one is a bit more indepth: http://www.journaldev.com/780/java-comparable-and-comparator-example-to-sort-objects

Besides: as stated before, use enums for your number-types. not because it's easier (imho) but because it is **much** faster comparing enums than comparing Strings.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a TreeSet collection, which sorts the entries.

```
TreeSet<PhoneNumber> sortedList = new TreeSet<>((PhoneNumber p1, PhoneNumber p2) -> p1.compareTo(p2));
```

Since you have to define an order for the entries, your PhoneNumber class will have to implement the Comparable interface and you need to override the compareTo() method to say that you will compare on the numberType

```
public int compareTo(Object o) {
    PhoneNumber p = (PhoneNumber) o;
    return numberType.equals(o.getNumberType())?0:numberType.equals("MOBILE")?-1:1;
}
```

However, better to use an `enum` if you want to add more number types in future